# Filename of downloaded file in data:Application/octet-stream;

Tags: html, data-uri

I am trying to download a file using data uri in following manner:

```
<input type="button"
  onclick="window.location.href='data:Application/octet-stream;content-disposition:attachment;filename=file.txt,${details}'"
  value="Download"/>
```

The problem is that the downloaded file is always named 'Unknown', whatever I try to use as 
filename. Is this the correct way to give the file a name ? or something else needs to be
done ?

Comment: So i think its not possible to give filename using dta-uri. Can it be done through javascript??

Answer (score 44):

Here's the solution, you just have to add a `download` attribute to anchor tag
`a` with desired name

```
<a href="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,Col1%2CCol2%2CCol3%0AVal1%2CVal2%2CVal3%0AVal11%2CVal22%2CVal33%0AVal111%2CVal222%2CVal333"
  download="somedata.csv">Example</a>
```

Another solution is to use JQuery/Javascript

[Anchor's Download Property](/a/13931279)

Comment: But how can it done with "OnClick= location href ?
i'm trying to figure this one..

Comment: @Ron, kindly check the link at the end of my solution, I think you may find there the answer which you are asking for.

Comment: @CristianTraìna, have you found a way?

Comment: @Vigrant no, I've a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760169/alternative-for-download-attribute-in-safari-ios) with no answers. By the way, I worked it around since I needed to download a pdf so I used `application/pdf`

Comment: If anyone ends up here, this _shoud_ be fixed in ios 13

Answer (score 6):

On Safari, you might want to use this, and instruct the user to ⌘-S the file:

```
window.open('data:text/csv;base64,' + encodeURI($window.btoa(content)));
```

Otherwise, this uses [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), but works ok:

```
    var downloadFile = function downloadFile(content, filename) {
      var supportsDownloadAttribute = 'download' in document.createElement('a');

      if(supportsDownloadAttribute) {
        var link = angular.element('<a/>');
        link.attr({
          href: 'data:attachment/csv;base64,' + encodeURI($window.btoa(content)),
          target: '_blank',
          download: filename
        })[0].click();
        $timeout(function() {
          link.remove();
        }, 50);
      } else if(typeof safari !== 'undefined') {
        window.open('data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(content));
      } else {
        var blob = new Blob([content], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, filename);
      }
    }
```

***Note***: There is some AngularJS in the code above, but it should be easy to factor out...

Comment: In iOS, this just opens a page with the base64 as text

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finally I solved in all browsers serving the CSV file in the server-side:

```
const result = json2csv({ data });

res.writeHead(200
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=issues.csv',
        'Content-Length': result.length
});

res.end(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that are using other libraries like angularjs or backbone, you can try something like this.

> $('a.download').attr('href', 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,'+$scope.data);

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for a client-side solution using Javascript only, here is mine, working on any browser except IE 10 and lower (and Edge...why?!):

```
var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute("download", "extract.csv");
link.setAttribute("href", uri);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
body.removeChild(body.lastChild);
```