# Anchor download attribute created with javascript not working on iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, download, anchor

I have a video/mp4 file saved in AWS S3 bucket, which should be downloaded from a client device (phone or computer) when the user clicks on an icon. I first make a request using **fetch**, and then create a **blob** object from the response. Next, I create an anchor element using javascript, I attach the href attribute and trigger it's click as on the code below:

```
fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename='file-name.mp4'",
      }),
    }).then((response): void => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log('Error', response);
      }

      response.blob().then((blob): void => {
        let videoUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = videoUrl;
        a.download = 'file-name.mp4';
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      });
    });
```

When testing this code, it works on Android Chrome and iOS Safari, but it doesn't on iOS Chrome. I can see that a request is fired but nothing happens, not even a new tab gets open.
I have tried some other approaches like using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library, also tried directly the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) like on the examples below, but still doesn't work.

```
fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename='file-name.mp4'",
      }),
    }).then((response): void => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log('Error', response);
      }

      response.blob().then((blob): void => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file-name.mp4');
      });
    });


fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename='file-name.mp4'",
      }),
    }).then((response): void => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log('Error', response);
      }

      response.blob().then((blob): void => {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

        reader.onloadend = (): void => {
            if (reader.result) {
                let url = reader.result.toString();

                window.open(url, '_blank');
           }
        };
      });
    });
```

The blob type is 'application/octet-stream'. Has anyone ever had a similar issue or has any other new approach idea? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue with a simple anchor with download attribute on Chrome for iOS...

Comment: It looks like a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760169/alternative-for-download-attribute-in-safari-ios It should be fixed in Chrome 99, I’ll explain in the other issue the why and how, but there’s no temporary fix.